# Python + How to merge two dictionaries with same key and value

Tags: python, arrays, django, dictionary

Sample dictionaries

```
skus = (
    {'sku': '53009', 'qtyonhand': '50'},
    {'sku': '53004', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
    {'sku': '53006', 'qtyonhand': '4'},
    {'sku': '53007', 'qtyonhand': '500'},
    {'sku': '53010', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
    {'sku': '53013', 'qtyonhand': '40'},
    {'sku': '53014', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
)

product_skus = [
    {'sku': '53009', 'line_id': 75128133},
    {'sku': '53004', 'line_id': 75453798},
    {'sku': '53006', 'line_id': 75504454},
    {'sku': '53007', 'line_id': 75504455},
    {'sku': '53010', 'line_id': 75504457},
    {'sku': '53013', 'line_id': 75504658},
    {'sku': '53014', 'line_id': 75504659},
]
```

**Trying to merge both dictionaries on the basis of the key-value pair.**
Need to merge both dictionaries on the basis of SKU and its value

```
Expected Output:
merged_skus = (
    {'sku': '53009', 'qtyonhand': '50', 'line_id': 75128133},
    {'sku': '53004', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75453798},
    {'sku': '53006', 'qtyonhand': '4', 'line_id': 75504454},
    {'sku': '53007', 'qtyonhand': '500', 'line_id': 75504455},
    {'sku': '53010', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504457},
    {'sku': '53014', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504659},
    {'sku': '53013', 'qtyonhand': '40', 'line_id': 75504658},
)
```

Comment: Do both `skus` and `product_skus` have the same values (as in all values in the first are in the second and vice-versa).

Comment: are `'sku'` values guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: Yes @go2nirvana, sku is unique

Comment: This is why databases were invented.

Comment: Why do you have a tuple of dictionaries?  Wouldn't it make more sense to have a single dictionary where `sku` was the key?

Comment: The system is collecting two different dictionaries from 2 different apps and needs to update the 3rd system on the basis of SKU, I will pick line-id and qty-on-hand to update db.

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
skus = (
    {'sku': '53009', 'qtyonhand': '50'},
    {'sku': '53004', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
    {'sku': '53006', 'qtyonhand': '4'},
    {'sku': '53007', 'qtyonhand': '500'},
    {'sku': '53010', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
    {'sku': '53013', 'qtyonhand': '40'},
    {'sku': '53014', 'qtyonhand': '20'},
)

product_skus = [
    {'sku': '53009', 'line_id': 75128133},
    {'sku': '53004', 'line_id': 75453798},
    {'sku': '53006', 'line_id': 75504454},
    {'sku': '53007', 'line_id': 75504455},
    {'sku': '53010', 'line_id': 75504457},
    {'sku': '53013', 'line_id': 75504658},
    {'sku': '53014', 'line_id': 75504659},
]

lookup = {element["sku"]: element for element in skus}

for product in product_skus:
    lookup[product["sku"]].update(product)

result = tuple(lookup.values())

for element in result:
    print(element)
```

**Output**

```
{'sku': '53009', 'qtyonhand': '50', 'line_id': 75128133}
{'sku': '53004', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75453798}
{'sku': '53006', 'qtyonhand': '4', 'line_id': 75504454}
{'sku': '53007', 'qtyonhand': '500', 'line_id': 75504455}
{'sku': '53010', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504457}
{'sku': '53013', 'qtyonhand': '40', 'line_id': 75504658}
{'sku': '53014', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504659}
```

As an alternative:

```
lookup = {element["sku"]: element for element in skus}
result = tuple({**product, **lookup[product["sku"]]} for product in product_skus)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can make a dictionary that boosts efficiency to lookup the values in the first collection for a given `sku` with:

```
skus_lookup = {
    s['sku']: s for s in skus
}

result = tuple(
    {**s, **skus_lookup[s['sku']] }
    for s in product_skus
)
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> pprint(result)
({'line_id': 75128133, 'qtyonhand': '50', 'sku': '53009'},
 {'line_id': 75453798, 'qtyonhand': '20', 'sku': '53004'},
 {'line_id': 75504454, 'qtyonhand': '4', 'sku': '53006'},
 {'line_id': 75504455, 'qtyonhand': '500', 'sku': '53007'},
 {'line_id': 75504457, 'qtyonhand': '20', 'sku': '53010'},
 {'line_id': 75504658, 'qtyonhand': '40', 'sku': '53013'},
 {'line_id': 75504659, 'qtyonhand': '20', 'sku': '53014'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.DataFrame(skus)
df2=pd.DataFrame(product_skus)
df3=df1.merge(df2)
res=df3.to_dict(orient='records')

>>> print(res)

[{'sku': '53009', 'qtyonhand': '50', 'line_id': 75128133}, {'sku': '53004', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75453798}, {'sku': '53006', 'qtyonhand': '4', 'line_id': 75504454}, {'sku': '53007', 'qtyonhand': '500', 'line_id': 75504455}, {'sku': '53010', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504457}, {'sku': '53013', 'qtyonhand': '40', 'line_id': 75504658}, {'sku': '53014', 'qtyonhand': '20', 'line_id': 75504659}]
```

or in one-liner:

```
pd.DataFrame(skus).merge(pd.DataFrame(product_skus)).to_dict(orient='records')
```